# Tesseract 4.0 for English handwritten text

Tags: image, ocr, tesseract

I want to know has anyone tried tesseract version 4.0(still in alpha I guess) for handwritten text.

From what I have read from its documentation it is now using LSTM, and claims to produce much better results.

I am thinking is it worth training tesseract(as now it implements LSTM) for handwritten text, or anyone else have any experience training tesseract.

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract 4.0 (alpha) is not working fine with Handwritten text. Its only for printed text but with LSTM ML model giving better accuracy than Tesseract 3.x, if you compare both version outputs you will get so much improve result.